# Hat matrix for regularised linear regression

Tags: regression, regularization, linear

In the blog post [here](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/loocv-linear-models/) it states that the diagonal of the hat matrix

```
H = X inv(X'X) X'
```

for a linear regression can be used to quickly calculate the leave one out cross validation error of the regression fit. To check if this is this only true for an *unregularised* linear fit I used the Octave code below

```
clear all
lambda = input( 'Enter lambda: ' ) ;
% data
y = rand(20,1) ;
X = [ ones(20,1) rand(20,5) ] ;
w = ( inv( X' * X + lambda * eye(size(X'*X)) ) * X' ) * y ;
y_fit = X * w ;
H = X * inv( X' * X + lambda * eye(size(X'*X)) ) * X' ;
yh_fit = H * y ;
both_fits = [ y_fit yh_fit ]
plot( y , 'b', y_fit , 'r' , yh_fit , 'g' )
```

to calculate a *regularised* linear fit and using the calculation

```
H = X * inv( X' * X + lambda * I ) * X' ;
```

for the hat matrix H, where lambda is the regularisation coefficient and I the identity matrix. Given that the numerical results, i.e. the y_fit using the weights and the yh_fit using the hat matrix, are the same, can I safely assume that the LOOCV statistic for a regularised fit can be calculated in the same way as outlined in the above linked blog post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Tikhonov regularized version of this is

$H=X(X^{T}X+\lambda I)^{-1}X^{T}$.

Comment: You added your answer while I was editing my question

Comment: Yes, but perhaps adding `(L2-norm) or "Ridge regression")` after "Tikhonov" in yr answer would help search engines reference yr perfectly fine answer better. Cheers.